# Responsive Navigation Dropdown Menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, navigation, nav

I can't seem to move the dropdown menu below the navigation. I've attempted a few different ways to make this happen, but I get confused with inline-block vs float and other techniques.

I've made a fiddle here:

jsfiddle.net/p1mrtuex/

As you can see, the dropdown menu pulls up to the side of the "portfolio" link on hover. I'd like it to be listed below the link for both the wide and narrow viewports.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing the "nav ul li:hover ul" to display:block should clear it.

```
nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This does indeed bring the sub-menu below the link. So thanks for the help! 

The next step I'd like to take would be to bring it below the nav menu instead of extending it. 

jsfiddle.net/p1mrtuex/2/

As you can see, the entire navigation menu extends to encompass the dropped menu.

Comment: or are you talking about the padding around the sub-menu on the small screen size?

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want to do something like this but try this:
    
        menu

- home

  portfolio

  - paintings
  - drawings
  - photography

  about

  contact

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/p1mrtuex/`
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend doing something like this with the mobile styles first.

```js
    $('.handle').on('click', function(){
        $('nav > ul').toggleClass('showing');
    });
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

header {
    background: #00795f;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

nav ul {
    background-color: #43a286;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    visibility:hidden;
    height:0;
    max-height:20em;
    overflow:scroll;
}
nav ul li a {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display:block;
    padding: 1.2em;
    text-align: left;
    line-height:1.2em;
}
.showing {
    height:auto;
    visibility:visible;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #399077;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
    height:auto;
    background-color:green;
}

.handle {
    background: #005c48;
    text-align: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
}

.handle img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .handle {
        display: none;
 }

    nav ul {
         overflow:visible;
    }

 nav > ul {
        height:auto;
        visibility:visible;
        text-align:center;
        margin:0 auto;
 }
    
    nav > ul > li {
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative;
    }

 nav > ul > li > ul {
        position:absolute;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <header>
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="#">LOGO GOES HERE</a>
    </div>
</header>
<nav>
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="#" alt="portfolio" >home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" alt="portfolio" >portfolio</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" alt="paintings" >paintings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="drawings" >drawings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="photography" >photography</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" alt="about the artist" >about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" alt="contact information" >contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="handle">
        <h4>menu</h4>
    </div>
</nav>
```